# Why can't I pass List<T> to a generic constructor parameter although all contraints are met?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code:

```cs
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection> where TCollection : class, IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private readonly TCollection _collection;

    public SampleClass() : this(new List<T>()) { }

    public SampleClass(TCollection collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the line containing the default constructor `public SampleClass() : this(new List<T>()) { }` does not compile. The error message says: **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'TCollection'**.

Why does this happen? `List<T>` actually meets all contraints that I placed on the TCollection generic: it is a class that implements `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Thank you so much for your help.

**EDIT: Updated code because it contained errors.**

Comment: Your `TCollection` is a generic type argument, so the user gets to decide, not you. When the user uses `SampleClass<int, Collection<int>>`, you create a `List<int>` and attempt to assign it to a field of type `Collection<int>`. This cannot work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

The problem is that I could write code like this:

```
class X : IList<int>, IReadOnlyList<int>
{
    ...
}
```

And then try to use it like this:

```
var instance = new SampleClass<int, X>();
```

But there is no conversion from `List<int>` to `X`.

The possibility of this scenario is why you get the compiler error message:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'TCollection'.

To get the "default of `List<T>`" behavior you're looking for, you could get rid of that default constructor and replace it with the following:

```
static class SampleClass
{
    public static SampleClass<T, List<T>> Create<T>()
    {
        return new SampleClass<T, List<T>>(new List<T>());
    }
}
```

This is a pattern similar to the `Tuple` static class with its static `Tuple.Create` generic method and the non-static `Tuple<T1>`, `Tuple<T1, T2>`, etc. classes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is you are assuming you can assign `List<T>` to a reference of type `TCollection`, without actually knowing what `TCollection` is. There are two approaches you can use here. The former is closer to what you currently have, while the latter allows you to write a class which is more easily used in a wider variety of scenarios.

1. Use the `new` constraint for `TCollection`. While you still don't know what type `TCollection` is, the compiler requires the type have a default constructor, allowing you to write this:

   ```
   public class SampleClass<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, new()
   {
       public SampleClass() : this(new TCollection()) { }

       public SampleClass(TCollection collection) { ... }
   }
   ```
2. Require calling code pass in the instance of `TCollection`, rather than create it yourself. In this case you would simply remove the default constructor.

Comment: Adding new constraint for `TCollection` would work but that's a strange requirement. What if `TCollection` needs some dependency? Simply design is flawed, need to think about it. Simply removing default constructor helps.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I added a note to the first paragraph explaining [my view] of the merits of each approach.

Comment: Well, in my context, I wanted to provide the default constructor to avoid a factory.

Comment: Somehow this feels like a DRY violation. In the probably standard scenario of `new SampleClass<T, List<T>>()` I have to repeat the `T` type twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change the generic constraint to `TCollection` and add the `new()` constraint. You can then initialize the class with `new TCollection()`

```
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection> where TCollection : class, IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, new()
{
    private readonly TCollection _collection;

    public SampleClass() : this(new TCollection()) { }

    public SampleClass(TCollection collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sam Harwell has part of the answer, you really want the `TCollection` to be something that contains `T` elements and so you should have:

```
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection>
  where TCollection : class, IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
```

However, this isn't enough to deal with the fact that you want to have a parameterless constructor that passes `new List<T>()` to the constructor that takes a `TCollection` argument. Something could be a `TCollection` and not be a `List<T>` or a base thereof, and therefore there isn't enough of a constraint to guarantee this would work.

There are three possible approaches. One, get rid of the parameterless constructor entirely:

```
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection> where TCollection : class, IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, new()
{
  private readonly TCollection _collection;

  public SampleClass(TCollection collection)
  {
    _collection = collection;
  }
}
```

Two, store the passed-in collection as `List<T>` and insist that `TCollection` be either it or derived from it (unlikely to be useful):

```
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection> where TCollection : List<T>
{
  private readonly List<T> _collection;

  public SampleClass() : this(new List<T>()) { }

  public SampleClass(TCollection collection)
  {
    _collection = collection;
  }
}
```

Three, insist that `TCollection` be a class with a parameterless constructor, and use that:

```
public class SampleClass<T, TCollection> where TCollection : class, IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, new()
{
  private readonly TCollection _collection;

  public SampleClass() : this(new TCollection()) { }

  public SampleClass(TCollection collection)
  {
    _collection = collection;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TCollection` is a class that you defined?

`List<T>` implements:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>,
       IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Does `TCollection` implement `IList`, `ICollection`, or inherit a base class of `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`? Your `TCollection` would have to implement or inherit one of these to remove the compiling error.

You would also need to change your class `TCollection` to `TCollection<T>` in order to accept a generically defined `new List<T>`. The generic needs to be passed to your collection somewhere.

Unless of course you place the constrains on defining what `TCollection` is. Which you might want to note that you put constraints on your generic `<T>` rather than `TCollection`.

Comment: `TCollection` is a generic with the constraints that it should be class that implements `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>`. I've updated the code a few minutes ago because I unfortunately put the contraints on the wrong generic.